# Intellisense in breakpoint condition window does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm faced problem. 
Intellisense does not work in conditional breakpoint window in my VS 2015. 
This behavior repeats on another machines ( mine and my colleagues).

Is anybody here seen this problem before?

Comment: Same problem for me. And others: also asked [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456299/vs2015-breakpoint-intellisense-doesnt-work) without answer yet.